# How can I make this graph animation in Python?

Tags: python, animation, turtle-graphics, python-turtle, spinning

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3d49.gif)

Hello, I need to create a Python program that simulates this animation.

I have been trying different libraries and come up with this code using turtle graphics. the problem is that the blue line is not working as it is approaching the beginning of itself.

This is the code:

```
import turtle


class SpinningCircle:
    def __init__(self):
        self.t1 = turtle.Turtle()
        self.t2 = turtle.Turtle()

        self.t1.hideturtle()
        self.t1.width(5)
        self.t1.pencolor("blue")
        self.t1.speed(0)

        self.t2.hideturtle()
        self.t2.width(5)
        self.t2.pencolor("grey")
        self.t2.speed(0)

    def move_t1(self, degrees):
        self.t1.circle(100, degrees)

    def move_t2(self, degrees):
        self.t2.circle(100, degrees)

    def coordinates_match(self):
        return int(self.t1.pos()[0]) == int(self.t2.pos()[0]) and int(self.t1.pos()[1]) == int(self.t2.pos()[1])

    def initiate_movement(self):
        self.move_t1(80)
        self.move_t2(40)

    def create_animation(self):
        while True:
            self.move_t1(4)
            self.move_t2(2)
            if self.coordinates_match():
                self.t1.clear()
                self.t2.clear()


grey_screen = turtle.Screen()
grey_screen.bgcolor("grey")

cool_function = SpinningCircle()

cool_function.initiate_movement()
cool_function.create_animation()

grey_screen.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 0):

I see some issues: your line isn't getting erased, you can try using a wider line for erasure, or, better yet, use `tracer()`, `clear()` and `update()`; you shouldn't have a `while True:`, use `ontimer()`; your `coordinates_match()` function is assuming an *exact* match which is an issue when dealing with floating point positions -- think small difference; this probably can be done with a single turtle:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

class SpinningCircle(Turtle):
    START_DELTA = 4
    EXTENT_DELTA = 7

    def __init__(self, radius=200, pen_width=5, color='blue'):
        super().__init__(visible=False)

        self.radius = radius
        self.circle_extent = 0

        self.width(pen_width)
        self.pencolor(color)
        self.penup()
        self.sety(-radius)

    def move(self):
        self.pendown()
        self.circle(self.radius, extent=self.circle_extent)
        self.penup()

        self.circle(self.radius, extent=self.START_DELTA - self.circle_extent)

        self.circle_extent = (self.circle_extent + self.EXTENT_DELTA) % 360

    def animate(self):
        self.clear()
        self.move()

        screen.update()
        screen.ontimer(self.animate)  # add 2nd argument, ms until call, to slow down

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor('grey')
screen.tracer(False)

instance = SpinningCircle()

instance.animate()

screen.exitonclick()
```

I agree, dealing with the situation where the ends meet is tricky.  Figuring out how to make the right thing happen naturally, not as a special case, is always the nicest solution.

Comment: This is a much nicer solution, thanks for the tips. I picked up the conditional statement to know where the end meets the start because it was the first that I came up with, and then thought that the issue was on another part of the code. Implementing the Turtle as a superclass is also a really good approach that I did not think of. I thought that using two turtles was the solution.